# How to vertically align div in another div with text?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to center a div vertically in a parent div, where text is present. Here's what I've got:

[image]

It looks a little funny because the text seems to be centered properly, but the yellow boxes aren't. This is how I'm doing it:

```
.btn {
      background-color: #ccc;
      color: #000;
      width: 200px;
      border: solid 1px black;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      display: table-cell;
}
.square {
      background-color: #ff0;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      display: inline-block;
}
.inner {
      display: inline-block;
}

<div class="btn">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Should my usage of "table-cell" + vertical-align be working? I only care about html5, I'm really just targeting the latest versions of mobile safari, so don't have to worry about older browsers etc.

Here's a js fiddle of this:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrJqF/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `vertical-align:top` on the square class. The extra space comes from space reserved for descendant text elements like j, g, y etc. that drop below the line.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TrJqF/1/)**

Comment: That almost works perfectly, but it looks like the vertical alignment of the text is slightly off because the ascenders/descenders are being taken in to account? For example, if the text is "Hello", it doesn't look right, there's more space below - but if the text is "Helylo", it looks good, because the "y" character is present. Any work arounds for that?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no difference between both the height. Apply yellow background color to inner class and see the difference in explicit and no height.

both square div doesn't have content and inner div have content. The css box aligning by itself based on its content. Add empty space to the square div as follows:

```
  <div class="btn">
   <div class="square">&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="inner">Hello</div>
   <div class="square">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
```

If you want you can add top and bottom margin 1 or 2 pixel which will show your expectation.

Comment: I hope adding one empty space (&nbsp;) will resolve your problem